# Can't install my own PyPi package: requirements can't be satisfied

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I am trying to publish a PyPI package. I am testing by first uploading to [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/). My `setup.py` is fairly simple:

```py
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# The directory containing this file
HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

# The text of the README file
README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

# This call to setup() does all the work
setup(
    name="my_package_name",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="My first Python package",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/my_package_url",
    author="John Smith",
    author_email="john.smith@gmail.com",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=("test",)),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "numpy",
        "scipy",
        "pandas",
        "statsmodels",
    ],
)
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/). Basically, once `setup.py` is prepared, I run

`python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

then

`twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`

Finally, to actually test my package installation, I create a new virtual environment and run

`pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ my_package_name`

However, I keep getting errors related to `pandas` and `statsmodels` requirements not being satisfied:

```sh
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from my_package_name) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas (from my_package_name)
```

Is it because TestPyPI doesn't have those packages (unlike PyPI)? Then how do people normally test end-to-end that their packages can be smoothly installed by other users?

Comment: Try adding the `--no-dependencies` flag to skip depedencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have only one index but you can have as many [extra indices](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-extra-index-url) as you wish. Add the main PyPI as an extra index:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ my_package_name
```

First `pip` looks into the index and then scan extra indices until it finds the package.